# Open Quantum Analogs to Classical Problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, soft-question, quantum-computing, cryptography

I am looking for interesting examples of complexity-theoretic and cryptographic problems where we have a significant amount of knowledge about the classical version of the problem, but we have no answers to analogous questions in the quantum case.

I can explain what I’m looking for by giving examples of cases that would have been good answers to my question, say, four years ago:

- Garbled Circuits: [Brakerski and Yuen](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01085) gave a construction for Quantum Randomized Encodings with quantum encoders and decoders.
- Zero-Knowledge Constant-Round Protocol for NP: [Bitansky and Shmueli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04769) gave a classical argument which was post-quantum secure

It would also be nice to have some explanation of the main challenge to developing a quantum analog, if there are a few factors that can be easily isolated.